# Javascript: 'click' button doesn't work when pressed?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm in practical JS by Gordon Zhu (wwww.watchandcode.com). I don't understand why the buttons appear in the browser/UI/client side, but for some reason, when I go to click it the button makes an animation and does nothing. You know, kind of like one of those old, old software programs some companies and job boards use.

I'm getting an

VM3950:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: todoList is not defined
    at :1:1

when defining todoList by displayTodos.addTodo('first');

```
       

        var todoList = {
  todos: [],
  displayTodos: function() {
    if (this.todos.length === 0) {
      console.log('Your todo list is empty!');
    } else {
      console.log('My todos:');
      for (var i = 0; i < this.todos.length; i++) {
        if (this.todos[i].completed === true) {
          console.log('(x)', this.todos[i].todoText);
        } else {
          console.log('( )', this.todos[i].todoText);
        }
      }
    }
  },
  addTodo: function(todoText) {
    this.todos.push({
      todoText: todoText,
      completed: false
    });
    this.displayTodos();
  },
  changeTodo: function(position, todoText) {
    this.todos[position].todoText = todoText;
    this.displayTodos();
  },
  deleteTodo: function(position) {
    this.todos.splice(position, 1)
    this.displayTodos();
  },
  toggleCompleted: function(position) {
    var todo = this.todos[position];
    todo.completed = !todo.completed;
    this.displayTodos();
  },
  toggleAll: function() {
    var totalTodos = this.todos.length;
    var completedTodos = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < totalTodos; i++) {
      if (this.todos[i].completed === true) {
        completedTodos++;
      }
    }
  }

if (completedTodos === totalTodos) {
      for (var i = 0; i < totalTodos; i++) {
        this.todos[i].completed = false;
      }

    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < totalTodos; i++); {
        this.todos[i].completed = true;
      }
    }

  this.displayTodos();
  }
};

var displayTodosButton = document.getElementById('displayTodosButton');

displayTodosButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  todoList.displayTodos();
});
              <h1>Todo List</h1>
            
            <button id = "displayTodosButton">Display Todos</button>
            <button id = "toggleAllButton">Toggle All</button>
```

Comment: It looks like you haven't grasped how `this` works in JavaScript https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this
If the rest of your code is correct, maybe it will work if you write `todoList.displayTodos()` and `todoList.toggleAll()` instead?

Comment: You have a couple of typos which probably isn't helping ... near the bottom: `var displayTodosButton = document.getElementById('dislayTodosButton');` - misspelt 'displayTodosButton'. Also I think there is an extra closing bracket where the `toggleAll` function is defined.

Answer (score 0):

`this` keyword works different in Javascript compared in other languages, `this` is determined by how a function is called (runtime binding). In your handlers you may called `todoList.displayTodos()` or you can also update to use arrow functions, because in arrow functions, this retains the value of the enclosing lexical context's `this` see your code below:

```js
var todoList = {
    todos: [],
    displayTodos: function() {
        if (this.todos.length === 0) {
            console.log('Your todo list is empty!');
        } else {
            console.log('My todos:');
            for (var i = 0; i < this.todos.length; i++) {
                if (this.todos[i].completed === true) {
                    console.log('(x)', this.todos[i].todoText);
                } else {
                    console.log('( )', this.todos[i].todoText);
                }
            }
        }
    },
  
    addTodo: function(todoText) {
        this.todos.push({
            todoText: todoText,
            completed: false
        });
        
        this.displayTodos();
    },
    changeTodo: function(position, todoText) {
        this.todos[position].todoText = todoText;
        this.displayTodos();
    },
    deleteTodo: function(position) {
        this.todos.splice(position, 1)
        this.displayTodos();
    },
    toggleCompleted: function(position) {
        var todo = this.todos[position];
        todo.completed = !todo.completed;
        this.displayTodos();
    },
    toggleAll: function() {
        var totalTodos = this.todos.length;
        var completedTodos = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < totalTodos; i++) {
            if (this.todos[i].completed === true) {
                completedTodos++;
            }
        }
    
    
        if (completedTodos === totalTodos) {
            for (var i = 0; i < totalTodos; i++) {
                this.todos[i].completed = false;
            }

        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < totalTodos; i++); {
            this.todos[i].completed = true;
            }
        }

        this.displayTodos();
    }
};

var displayTodosButton = document.getElementById('displayTodosButton');
var toggleAllButton = document.getElementById('toggleAllButton');

displayTodosButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  this.todoList.displayTodos();
});

toggleAllButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  this.todoList.toggleAll();
});
```

```html
<h1>Todo List</h1>
<button id = "displayTodosButton">Display Todos</button>
<button id = "toggleAllButton">Toggle All</button>
```

Comment: I'm impressed, the inclusion of "=>" in place of the "()" made all the difference

Answer (score 0):

The error display is : Uncaught ReferenceError: todoList is not defined
Which means exactly that when referencing the **todoList object** from the **this** context it won't be defined because the **this** here is your **html element** not the **window object** thus if you want to refer to your **object** you have to remove the **this** keyword that's all (The javascript **this** keyword has a different behavior from many other languages).
Finally if you want to read more about the this behavior in java-script you can visit : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this